# Why is this answer that does not even have a link spam or offensive?

Tags: support, disputed-review-audits, deleted-answers, spam, low-quality-answers

I got a *'STOP! Look and listen.'* from clicking <kbd>Looks OK</kbd> [here](https://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/34903819). For whatever reason the answer is considered spam and was deleted as such. Sometimes the answers have a link to an undisclosed affiliated site but this answer in particular **does not appear to have any links at all:**

[image: Answer]

This raises a couple questions:

- Could a moderator please verify that this answer is actually spam, and if not, undelete and unlock the answer, and if so, use a R/A flag or something to remove it from the audit system?
- How could a post like this be spam? How could a post be spam without even containing an offsite link?

Comment: Because an editor decided it was a brilliant idea to edit out the spam link; it's still CGPT spam (as in CGPT content written exclusively for the sake of sneaking in spam, though one could quite trivially argue all CGPT content mindlessly dumped onto the site is spam), hence the deletion. The edit should've been rolled back to avoid confusion in audits

Comment: The handling of that specific account is not something we're going to discuss, but I concur with Zoe that editing out spam links is really really not something we should be doing. I've rolled back the edit, though hopefully it's not _more_ confusing in future audits seeing a mod had edited the post and left it that way...

Comment: Undelete and re-nuke it as R/A. That'll exclude it from future audits

Comment: To be explicit: the original version had the word "variable" linked to some JavaScript tutorial, while the answer is about Bash and appears GPT-generated.